# Android - Does requesting permission to write external storage make devices incompatible in the Play Store that do not have external storage options?

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, device-compatibility

If an application uses permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE will devices that do not have an external storage option, such as an sd card, be listed as incompatible once the application is uploaded to the Google Play Store?

We have a user with a Nexus 7 (2012) who sees our application as being incompatible with their device in the Play Store even though they have above the min OS.  I believe the Nexus 7 (2012) has no external storage option and our app is requesting the permission.  Could this be why the user sees their device as being incompatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe the Nexus 7 (2012) has no external storage option

All Nexus devices have external storage. All Android devices that legitimately ship with the Play Store are required to have 1GB of external storage at minimum.

> devices that do not have an external storage option, such as an sd card

You are conflating [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) with [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

> Could this be why the user sees their device as being incompatible?

No.